# Change transition-duration with add/removeClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a simple pen with a button. When "on" is pressed the cover should slide and cover "on". When "off" is pressed the cover should cover "off". It works the way I have it, but when I try to add some transition effects nothing works. I tried adding `transition-duration: 1s;` to every class in the project but no luck.

Here's my codepen.
https://codepen.io/Alex-Iron/pen/eMORVV

My code is this:

HTML

```
<div id="switch" class="silver-background">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="silver-background" id="cover">
      <div id="cover-inner"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="on" class="on-left">on</div>
    <div id="off">off</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
$radius: 7px;
$height: 100px;
$width: $height*1.5;

#switch{
  width: $width*2.1;
  height: $height*1.2;
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
}
.silver-background{
  border-radius: $radius;
  background: silver;
}
#wrapper{
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
}
#on, #off, #cover, #cover-inner{
  font-size: $height/3;
  height: $height;
  width: $width;
  line-height: $height;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#on{
  background: radial-gradient(green, green, black);
  border-radius: $radius 0 0 $radius;
  color: lightgreen;
}
#off{
  background: radial-gradient(#A00000, #A00000, black);
  border-radius: 0 $radius $radius 0;
  color: #EC6666*1.3;
}
#cover{
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: $width*2.1/2;
  height: $height*1.2;
  display: grid;
  top: 0;
}
#cover-inner{
  width: $width*0.9;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: $radius;
  margin: auto;
}
.on-left{
  left: 0;
}
.on-right{
  right: 0;
}
```

My jQuery code.

```
$("#off").on('click',()=>{
  $('#cover').removeClass('on-left');
  $('#cover').addClass('on-right');
});
$('#on').on('click',()=>{
  $('#cover').removeClass('on-right');
  $('#cover').addClass('on-left');
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your pen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/geOpgz

You should use the `transition` property of css:

```
#cover{
  ...
  left: 0;
  transition: 1s left;
}
```

The transition property can be used to animate a property value change. It is important, that your class only changes a property value f.e. `left` and not switches from `left: 0` to `right: 0`:

```
#cover.on-left{
  left: 0;
}
#cover.on-right{
  left: $width;
}
```

In your case, the new value of your left property on right position is `left: $width*2.1 / 2` cause your wrapper has the following width: `width: $width*2.1`.

By the way, i yould suggest you to use the `toggleClass` function of jquery:

```
$("#wrapper").on('click',()=>{
  $('#cover').toggleClass('on-right');
});
```

Now you can click your wrapper on any position and it toggles the "on" and "off" with only one class `.on-right` and less javascript code:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QmWjwb

Comment: This solution doesn't have the initial class so the first switch doesn't have the transition

Answer (score 1):

Your id="cover" should have `on-left` from start, and then give that `#cover` property `transition: left 0.2s ease` and class `.on-right` should have `left: 150px` since you cant transition from `left: 0` to `right: 0`.

Here is the updated pen: https://codepen.io/zmuci/pen/JLjdEb